# Wildfly-Thorntail failing to connect to MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb, thorntail

I need to upgrade my Wildfly-Thorntail from 2.2 to 2.3 to resolve a compatibility issue with Maven 3.6. Under Maven 3.5 with 2.2, the project builds and runs perfectly, but under 3.6 it complains with "An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.thorntail:thorntail-maven-plugin".

After changing Thorntail to 2.3,0 (hardcoded here for brevity), i.e.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

...the program builds correctly, but now I get this error during program startup:

```
2019-02-16 21:54:22,159 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0114: Failed to load datasource class:     com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"
```

A few lines down:

```
21:54:23,482 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
   ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
   ("data-source" => "my_ds")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" =>  ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.my_ds is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/datasources/my_ds is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"
    ] 
}
```

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="SPU" transaction-type="JTA">

    <!-- The "Java-Transaction-API" datasource here refers to the datasource defined in /src/main/resources/project-defaults.yml. -->
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/my_ds</jta-data-source>

    <!-- User and password defines in project-defaults.yml -->
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

...in my POM, I have the following connector defined:

```
<!-- The driver used to access MariaDB, automatically detected by Thorntail and registered -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

I have been stuck since this morning due to my limited knowledge of Wildfly-Thorntail.  Any assistence will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks OK on the first sight. Do you have a minimal but complete reproducer somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

In 8.x version (that's what your maven indicate), the name of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL Connector/J has changed from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. The old class name has been deprecated.

Or since you use MariaDB server, according driver is :

```
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    xa-datasource-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource
```

with maven :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```